# Forces Involved with Uniform Circular Motion

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

Lets suppose we have some object attach to a pole via a rope and is travelling in uniform circular motion. Assuming that we are looking down on this system and air resistance and friction are negligible. Then there is a centripetal force pulling the object towards the pole acting along the rope and the direction of this force is constantly changing as the object travels around its path. However, the object does not get pulled into the pole as it is maintaining a circular path, so what other force in this system is counteracting this centripetal force and keeping the object in its circular path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> so what other force in this system is counteracting this centripetal
> force and keeping the object in its circular path?

You are looking at it backwards. The centripetal force is keeping the object from moving at constant speed in a straight line tangent to the circle due to its inertia.

Newton's first law states: *an object at rest remains at rest, and an object in motion remains in motion at constant speed and in a straight line unless acted on by an unbalanced force.* This means a net (unbalanced) force can cause a change in the speed and/or a change in direction of motion.

In the case of uniform circular motion (motion of an object moving at constant speed in a circle) the only force acting on the object is the centripetal force acting to prevent the object from moving in a straight line and without changing its speed.

You can think of the centripetal force as counteracting inertia. The centripetal force pulls the object inward to follow a curved path, while the mass appears to push outward due to its inertia. In the accelerating frame of the object this outward push, which is an apparent outward force since it is not due to physical contact, is called the centrifugal force.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

There is no other force.

> object does not get pulled into the pole as it is maintaining a circular path

You say that the object is not *pulled* into the rod, but you mean that it does not *get close* to the rod. These two statements are not the same. For another example of this, take a ball and throw it upward. At the beginning of the motion, the ball *is being puled down*, but *isn't getting closer to the ground*.

Where does this confusion come from? Our intuition sometimes tells us that the velocity is in the same direction as the force. But this is not true- the *change in velocity* is in the direction of the force.

If you look at your spinning object, the velocity is tangent to the circle, but the *acceleration* (the *change* in velocity) is in fact towards the center, as it should. This can be seen by drawing the velocity vectors in two close times, and subtracting them- this is a geometric fact. No other force required!

Answer (score 0):

There is no other force. The object just wants to continue moving straight ahead. Had the inwards centripetal force not been there, then the object would fly off tangentially away from the circle. But the centripetal force *is* present and pulls inwards to make the object turn.